# Contact Form plugin - Not receiving emails at separate addresses

Tags: plugin-contactform

I have implemented the Craft contact form plugin, and have my form set to send to two email addresses. I am receiving messages at one address, but my client is not receiving any messages at the other. Their email address is the same domain as the website.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you're on the latest version of the [plugin](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm). There was a bug related to sending to multiple addresses that got fixed several months ago.

If that's not it, have them check their SPAM folder to see if it's getting trapped in there.

If it's not in SPAM, then try using a different email protocol under Settings->Email in the control panel, preferably SMTP based.  phpmail is notoriously unreliable at email delivery.